# Lithium models for Users and Friends

Tags: php, mysql, lithium

Trying to create relationships in my Models for User accounts and Friends.

Working from this example, https://github.com/masom/li3_microblog , but I ultimately get an error that I think indicates a failure to find a field user_id in the Friends table, a field I've not specified anywhere.

Here are my MySQL tables:

```
users        friends
-----        -------
id           id ( just the primary key )
username     uid ( foreign key to users.id )
             friend_uid ( foreign key to users.id )
```

User Model:

```
namespace app\models;

class Users extends \lithium\data\Model {
    public $hasMany = array('Friends' => array('keys'=>array('id'=>'uid')));
}
```

Friend model:

```
namespace app\models;

class Friends extends \lithium\data\Model {
    public $belongsTo = array(
         'Friend' => array('to'=>'app\models\Users','keys'=>array('friend_uid'=>'id')),
         'User' => array('to'=>'app\models\Users','keys'=>array('uid'=>'id'))
    );
}
```

UsersController.php

```
namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\Users;
use app\models\Friends;

class UsersController extends \lithium\action\Controller {

  public function index() {

    $conditions = array('Users.id'=>$this->request->id);
    $with = array('Friends');

    $user = Users::find('first',compact('conditions','with'));

    $conditions = array('Friends.friend'=>$user->id);
    $with = array('Friend');
    $friends = Friends::all(compact('conditions','with'));

    return compact('user','friends');        

 }

}
```

With that I get a fatal error, it's trying to find a field user_id in the Friends table:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Friends.user_id' in 'on clause'' in /Users/path/Documents/mamp_root/name/libraries/lithium/data/source/database/adapter/MySql.php:
```

Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?

Comment: I think you should change:
 `code`$conditions = array('Friends.friend'=>$user->id);`code`
to:
 `code`$conditions = array('Friends.uid'=>$user->id);`code`

Also, are you really using the first $with = array('Friends'). If not remove it for performance.

Comment: Also, check your resulting SQL by adding a var dump like
`code`protected function _execute($sql, array $options = array()) {
 var_dump($sql);
`code`
The file is /libraries/lithium/data/source/database/adapter/MySql.php

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the tutorial was last updated a year ago. I know at some point the configuration options changed from `'keys'` to `'key'`, so you could try that.